# Actual usage of union in C

Tags: c, unions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: Where is union practically used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951269/c-where-is-union-practically-used)

I know the concept of union but I don't see the actual case in real world coding that I should use union data structure. I will be very appreciated if you guys can give me some examples or tutorials that shows cases using union properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724617/examples-of-union-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I use it constantly: parsing a configuration file I store all values in a union data type. E.g. when values can be int types or strings, I would use a data structure as follows:

```
struct cval_s {
  short type;
  union {
    int ival;
    char *cval;
  } val;
};
```

In complexer problems, I use them, too. E.g. once I wrote an interpreter for an easy scripting language, and a value in this language was represented by a struct containing a union.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine having a `struct` that keeps a value and the type of that value. When the type is set to a particular type, you would only need to use one of the members of the `union` rather than waste space for three of them when you use only one simultaneously.

```
struct {
  int type;

  union {
    int intval;
    double dval;
    char cval;
  } value;
}
```