# Why use typedef on struct and union?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I was wondering why you would use the specifier typedef on the types struct and union, because aren't they somewhat used to define your own type anyways?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a C thing, not a C++ thing.

Comment: @user2357112, sure? I mean, I have seen it been used in C++?

Comment: The question does apply to C++ but maybe tag it C as well?

Comment: Seen it used by whom and in what context?

Comment: @Skizz - I would expect a user with high rep to know tags are for specifying the field of the question, and not for making your own answer correct

Comment: Probably because older c++ programmers all started with C, and got in the habit of doing this, even though it is not needed in c++.

Comment: @StoryTeller, here is one the places I saw it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1951401/7926026

Comment: There is no reason ever to use `typedef` when defining a `struct` or `union`. There. I said it.

Comment: and why are you saying that this is more C and C++? :/

Comment: Yeah, I'd definately put myself in the ;'older' category :-)

Comment: `C` programmers do it so they don't need to type `struct` everywhere. `C++` doesn't have that issue.

Comment: @Hei - The question you linked is doubly tagged with C and C++. The answer is pure C. C++ programmers don't do it, not unless writing C bindings to their C++ library, any way.

Comment: Thanks guys! Let me try to read everything here and I will leave a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*
Reading the standard the 'typedef' isn't required in C++ and is probably there for backward compatibility. Also, with 'typedef' the code would compile in both C and C++ compilers without change or '#if define' around it so it's probably a legacy code support thing.

I think people do it to save on typing! We're a lazy lot afterall. So instead of:-

```
struct SomeStruct
{
  // some data
};

struct SomeStruct first_instance;
struct SomeStruct second_instance;
```

you'd have this instead:-

```
typedef struct typedefSomeStruct
{
  // some data
} SomeStruct;

SomeStruct first_instance;
SomeStruct second_instance;
```

So when you declare instances of the type you don't need to prefix the 'struct' keyword.

Comment: This is really a holdover from C, as C++ doesn't require the `struct` keyword when declaring them.

Comment: This is tagged C++, you don't need to prefix it either way

Comment: This answer doesn't work for `C++`.